# Sharing Database Across Multiple Apps

Tags: security, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Web App #1 is on AWS and contains user subscription information (e.g. is a subscription active) and allows users to create accounts.

Web App #2 is behind a VPN, and would ideally sync up with Web App #1 so user's can use the same credentials to access services, and we can validate that they have an active subscription.  I'm not worried about VPN authorization, I handle that separately.  This is purely for access to Web App #2's resources.

Both web apps are written in Flask using SQLAlchemy.  How is best to synchronize these apps over the Internet?

I figured just have Postgres listening for any connection would probably not be ideal.  Is the traffic over TLS/SSL?  Is this what sharding the database is used for?

Comment: I would argue a regular flow is to have separate databases and create a license service that checks if the user had a valid license/subscription.

Comment: @djthoms: that sounds great.  I was hoping for something like that.  How can I best share credentials across the apps then?

Comment: As requested, putting as a comment instead of as an answer: Why aren't you just putting the database on a server and make the apps connect to that database? Way easier than having them connect to each other and undergo a sync, just have them use the same database directly. And if that's what you're doing I don't see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario above, it sounds like just having the database accessible to both locations would be fine. Put Postgres on a separate VM accessible to both.

Limit access to the Postgres listener as coming from only your app IPs. You can do this through AWS.

Enable authentication to Postgres -- certificate-based auth sounds like it would be best in your case, which would also run over TLS.

Sharding is about splitting data based on some attribute -- for example, say you had 1,000,000 users, each with a row in a "users" table. You could shard that out over 4 separate database servers, and everyone with a username A-H goes to server #1, I-N goes to server #2, etc. Sharing is primarily used to improve read/write performance.